# Creating exe file using nuitka python

Tags: python-3.x, mingw, nuitka

I installed nuitka version 5.27.0 (`conda install -c conda-forge nuitka`) on 32bit windows7 with a 32bit python3.6 anaconda. I also installed `mingw32` on `C:\MinGW`, in which version of gcc is 6.3.0. I also installed python2.7 on `C:\Python27` as a requirement for running nuitka. I created the python 3.5 environment to run the nutika. when trying to create the exe file by typing this on cmd (nuitka test.py), the following error shows up:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py35\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\include/nuitka/fibers.h:56:43: error: unknown type name 'uintptr_t'
>    int _prepareFiber( Fiber *to, void *code, uintptr_t arg );
>                                              ^~~~~~~~~
>   scons: ***[test.build\module.__main__o] Error1

any thoughts on that? Thank you